# Django How to customize forms file input

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, tailwind-css

I working with Django & Tailwind CSS project where needs to upload image. I use forms to do this. Now form looks like:

```
image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
    "class": "bg-nav-blue rounded-xl",
}
))
```

But for now it's looks like this one. But for my design I need button

[image]

How to customize view of this form?

Comment: since we cannot read the text in your image, it's not clear what's wrong here (please use english). This looks like a button to me. What do you mean by "I need button"? What should happen when the user clicks the button?

Comment: It's the standart bottom of file input form
Bottom placed on the left side (chose a file), in the right side - text (File not chosen)

When the user click the button we choice a photo
I looking for a way how customize this

Comment: Explain “customize”. You’ve already customised it with a different look. You can also look at the generated HTML and use that as a start to customize further. Just put the HTML directly in your template. It’s not clear what you want.